# How can I test multiple inputs from console?

Tags: java, testing, input

I need to test input from console in my program:

**`Main.java`** - class with main logic.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Integer dividend = new IntegerReader().fetchIntegerNumber("Input dividend: ");
        final Integer divisor = new IntegerReader().fetchIntegerNumber("Input divisor: ");
        System.out.println(dividend);
        System.out.println(divisor);
    }
}
```

**`IntegerReader.java`** - reads integer number from input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerReader {

    public Integer fetchIntegerNumber(final String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        return Integer.valueOf(inputString);
    }
}
```

**`MainTest.java`** - test of Main.java class.

```
class MainTest {
    private final InputStream testInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("2\n3".getBytes());
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream testOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private InputStream initialInputStream = System.in;
    private PrintStream initialOutputStream = System.out;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpStreams() {
        System.setIn(testInputStream);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOutputStream));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void restoreDefaultStreams() {
        System.setIn(initialInputStream);
        System.setOut(initialOutputStream);
        System.out.println("Test initial output stream");
    }

    @Test
    void fetchesTextFromInput() {
        Main.main(new String[]{});
        final String actual = testOutputStream.toString();
        assertThat(actual, is("Input dividend: Input divisor: 2\n3"));
    }
}
```

When I run test, I get exception: `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`.

This exception is thrown, if I try to read second number (`divisor`) on line:

```
final String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
```

How can I fix test, so that exception will not occur?

Comment: In which line is this exception occuring?

Comment: @michaeak I have edited question. I added line on which exception is occured.

Comment: But it happens in the second invocation of it, right? Or directly in the first?

Comment: If you delete the command `scanner.close()` in `fetchIntegerNumber` the Exception doesn't show up for me anymore.

Comment: @michaeak it happens only in the second invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design the IntegerReader in the way that it accepts a scanner:

```
public class IntegerReader {

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public IntegerReader(Scanner theScanner) {
        this.scanner = theScanner;
    }

    public Integer fetchIntegerNumber(final String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        final String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        return Integer.valueOf(inputString);
    }
}
```

The main class would look like this:

```
public class Main {
    private Scanner scanner;

    public Main(Scanner theScanner) {
        this.scanner = theScanner;
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Main(new Scanner(System.in)).process();
    }

    public void process() {
        final Integer dividend = new IntegerReader(scanner).fetchIntegerNumber("Input dividend: ");
        final Integer divisor = new IntegerReader(scanner).fetchIntegerNumber("Input divisor: ");
        System.out.println(dividend);
        System.out.println(divisor);
    }
}
```

The test then looks the following way:

```
// this test still fails, but. ..
public class MainTest {
private final InputStream testInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("2\n3\n".getBytes());
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream testOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintStream initialOutputStream = System.out;

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOutputStream));
    }

    @After
    public void restoreDefaultStreams() {
        System.setOut(initialOutputStream);
        System.out.println("Test initial output stream");
    }

    @Test
    public void fetchesTextFromInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(testInputStream);
        Main main = new Main(scanner);
        main.process();
        final String actual = testOutputStream.toString();
        Assert.assertEquals("Input dividend: Input divisor: 2\n3", actual);
    }
}
```

In this way the scanner is not closed.
Note that the test is not green. I used JUnit, I don't know which technology you used.

**Please note:**

1. If I design a class I would not make it dependend on System.*, but give it some stream to work with. This eases testing.
2. if you use **new** anywhere in your code you need to know whether the class has the concern to do this or if someone else, a builder or factory should rather create this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to invoke `scanner.close();` because `Scanner.close()` will close the underlying `Closable` instance, here `System.in` and so your dummy test inputstream  will be discarded.
Besides even by removing the explicit closing operation it will still fails at runtime :

```
public Integer fetchIntegerNumber(final String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
    // REMOVED scanner.close();
    return Integer.valueOf(inputString);
}
```

because the method return will make the scanner eligible to be GC and so `System.in` will still be closed.
What you want is that `System.in.close()` be not invoked.
You have two simple ways : Prevent this invocation from the scanner instance or  from the underlying resource instance directly (`System.in`). 
You could decorate `System.in` with  `FilterInputStream`.

For example :

```
InputStream inWithoutClose = new FilterInputStream(System.in) {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Then modify the method to test to make it accept this object.